# Use a specific column from a result set of a SELECT in another SELECT statement in same SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SELECT statement which gives me a result set containing ID as a column name. I want to use the ID column in another select. Is there any possible way to do this

```
SELECT A.Id
      ,B.Product
      ,A.Name
      ,B.ProductCode
FROM Customers A
INNER JOIN Product B ON A.Id = B.Id
```

I want to use the resulting column A.Id in another Select

```
SELECT * FROM SELLER WHERE ID = 'A.ID'(How to get this A.ID??)
```

I need to use this logic inside a Stored Procedure where I have If else condition. So I am not able to use temporary table with same name here.

Comment: You want to show the first query result also?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the first query result in Table1 and Second query result in table two when executing the SP

Comment: Ugly way: `where ID in (select A.ID from Customers A INNER JOIN Product B ON A.Id = B.Id)`

Comment: If you did not get the answer, you should elaborate your question a bit more.

Comment: If you are using the same query you might just put your result in a temp table and work from the table. Ofc its very project sensitive and it might slow you down so think about it. Also it would be nice to see what is the other query that is using the same column.

Answer (score 0):

That's very simple. Just join another source table also to the procedure

```
SELECT A.Id
      ,S.*
      ,B.Product
      ,A.Name
      ,B.ProductCode
FROM Customers A
LEFT JOIN Product B ON A.Id = B.Id
LEFT JOIN SELLER S ON S.ID = A.ID
```